# Pandas to_json not outputting null for NaT

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using Pandas 0.12.0 and am seeing some behaviour that contradicts the docs when converting a series or dataframe to json.

If I create a series with a few dates that includes null values, I get something like this:

```
>>> s = pandas.Series(data=[datetime.datetime.now(), datetime.datetime.now(), None])
>>> s
0    2013-11-07 16:10:47.530771
1    2013-11-07 16:10:47.530782
2                          None
dtype: object
```

According to http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#writing-json, when converting to json, None, NaT and NaN values should be output as null.

If I then output to_json, I get a null for the third entry, as expected.

```
>>> s.to_json()
'{"0":1383840647530771000,"1":1383840647530782000,"2":null}'
```

However, I need to make sure the datatype is datetime64[ns] for some other calculations, so  I convert the fields to datetime in Pandas like so:

```
>>> t = pandas.to_datetime(s)
>>> t
0   2013-11-07 16:10:47.530771
1   2013-11-07 16:10:47.530782
2                          NaT
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

The None is now a NaT, which is consistent and expected.  Then I try to output json again, I get a negative value for the NaT value instead of the null I was expecting.

```
>>> t.to_json()
'{"0":1383840647530771000,"1":1383840647530782000,"2":-9223372036854775808}'
```

It gets even worse when using iso format since it tries to format the date, but most parsers can't figure out how to handle the output date and this wreaks all kinds of havoc down the line.

```
>>> t.to_json(date_format='iso')
'{"0":"2013-11-07T16:10:47.530771","1":"2013-11-07T16:10:47.530782","2":"0001-255-255T00:00:00"}'
```

Any thoughts on how I should proceed here? Thanks!

**EDIT**:

Looks like this is a problem with the string representation of pandas.NaT?

```
>>> str(pandas.NaT)
'0001-255-255 00:00:00'
```

Comment: FWIW I can't reproduce this in trunk, which I pulled earlier today; I get `'{"0":1383841824833,"1":1383841824833,"2":null}'` and `'{"0":"2013-11-07T16:30:24.833Z","1":"2013-11-07T16:30:24.833Z","2":null}'`, respectively.

Comment: iirc this was fixed early on dev for 0.13. 0.13 rc is coming out early next week / u can try on master to validate that it has been fixed. alternatively you can stringify before passing to_json

Comment: Confirmed that this is fixed in trunk/0.13, thanks guys.  I had done a quick search in the issues list but didn't come across this one.  Jeff, I'll try out your hacky workaround until 0.13 is released.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit hacky, but you could do this

```
 In [13]: s = Series(pd.to_datetime(['20130101',None]))

 In [14]: s
 0   2013-01-01 00:00:00 
 1                   NaT
 dtype: datetime64[ns]

 In [15]: def f(x):
             if isnull(x): 
                return 'null'
             return x.isoformat()    ....: 

 In [16]: s.apply(f).to_json() 

 Out[16]:
 '{"0":"2013-01-01T00:00:00","1":"null"}'
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff, this mostly worked.  I changed it to `return None`, otherwise the json has the string 'null' instead of an actual null value.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Just create a custom encoder:

```
class CustomEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if pd.isnull(obj):
            return None
        elif isinstance(obj, datetime):
            return obj.isoformat()
        elif isinstance(obj, date):
            return obj.isoformat()
        elif isinstance(obj, timedelta):
            return (datetime.min + obj).time().isoformat()
        else:
            return super(CustomEncoder, self).default(obj)
```

Then use it to encode a dataframe:

```
df_as_dict = df.to_dict(outtype = 'records')  # transform to dict

df_as_json = CustomEncoder().encode(df_as_dict) #transform to json
```

Since the encoder standardized the data, the regular decoder will act fine in transforming it back to a dataframe:

```
result_as_dict = json.JSONDecoder().decode(df_as_json) # decode back to dict

result_as_df = pd.DataFrame(result_as_dict)  # transform dict back to dataframe
```

Of course this will also work if you put the dataframe into a larger dict before encoding, e.g

```
input_dict = {'key_1':val_1,'key_2':val_2,...,'df_as_dict':df_as_dict}
input_json = CustomEncoder().encode(input_dict)
input_json_back_as_dict = json.JSONDecoder().decode(input_json)
input_df_back_as_dict = input_json_back_as_dict['df_as_dict']
input_df_back_as_df = pd.DataFrame(input_df_back_as_dict)
```